# Pivot 2 rows bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot

How can I pivot 2 rows into columns?

```
ID|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4
1 |a    |A    |Q    |5000
1 |a    |B    |Q    |8000
2 |a    |A    |R    |4000
2 |a    |B    |T    |6000
```

Into:

```
ID|col_1|A_col3|A_col4|B_col3|B_col4
1 |a    |Q     |5000  |R     |4000
2 |a    |Q     |8000  |T     |6000
```

where the values in col_2 is now the column headnings and values of col_3 and col_4 are the aggerated in the pivot.

I tried this but stuck on the next step and does not give wanted outouts:

```
select * from 
(
  select ID, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 from tableA
) as A
pivot (max(col_3) for col_2 in ('A','B'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when col_2 = 'A' then col_3 end) as a_col3,
       max(case when col_2 = 'A' then col_4 end) as a_col4,
       max(case when col_2 = 'B' then col_3 end) as b_col3,
       max(case when col_2 = 'B' then col_4 end) as b_col4
from tablea
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this but stuck on the next step ...

Consider below approach

```
select *
from tableA
pivot (max(col_3) as col3, max(col_4) as col4 for col_2 in ('A', 'B'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]